# Can't disable animation in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want disable animation after user checked on checkbox, but I can't get it to work.

```
 function onChangeTarget(num) {
            updateCounter();
            if (num != 0) {
                targetHideAnimation = parseInt(num);
                $('div.plus-point.plus-point' + num + '').css("display", "block");
                $('div#wrap-' + num + ' img').css("filter", "grayscale(1)");
                if (targetHideAnimation != 0) {
                    $('div#wrap-' + num + '').stop();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here my full source code : 
https://jsfiddle.net/ninhnguyen2208/o4htr5xj/

Please tell me what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your fiddle, the issue isn't with the `.stop()`, it's with the `.animate`, specifically the callback:

```
     function upDown() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= QTY_TARGETS; i++) {
            ...
            wrap.animate({ 'top': '' + moveTop + 'px' }, {
                duration: duration,
                complete: function () {
                    wrap.animate({ top: '' + moveTopRepeat + '' },
                    {
                        duration: duration,
                        // this line here
                        complete: upDown
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The `complete:upDown` restarts upDown, but is called form within every target and calls the outer upDown*All*.

Separate upDown to upDownAll and an inner upDownTarget then on the individual target complete reset just for that target:

```
    function upDown() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= QTY_TARGETS; i++) {
            upDownTarget(i)
        }
    }
    function upDownTarget(i)
    {
      ...
      wrap.animate({ 'top': '' + moveTop + 'px' }, {
        duration: duration,
        complete: function () {
          wrap.animate({ top: '' + moveTopRepeat + '' },
                       {
            duration: duration,

            // only restart this one target
            complete: function() { upDownTarget(i) }
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

Updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/29hntbve/

---

As an extra, you also might like to stop the animations when the player loses:

```
res.text('You lose');
$(".wrap").stop();
```

Comment: Yes, thanks bro so much.